# Bootstrap Tags Input - Add Between Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I have a tag input field where I have to make some changes.
For example, I have this field previously ->
[image: Initial State]

I move the cursor back with my arrow keys and delete the "test" tag ->
[image: Deleted Tag]

I then re-enter it again in that same location ->
[image: Entered Again]

I press the right arrow key and put the cursor back to it's location. I submit the form like shown in the previous picture with the order "test,phrase". But the result comes as "phrase,test". I would like to preserve the order in which I edited it. Any idea what's wrong here ?

[image]

The HTML code->

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control" name="phrases" placeholder="Enter Phrases In Order" value="<?php echo $phrases;?>" required>
</div>
```

The php variable $phrases is being retreived from MySQL in a comma separated format.

```
$phrases="test,phrase";
```

Not much code really. I just want to preserve the order after I have edited it.

Comment: I don't have any idea. Without the code. Please provide the code.

Comment: @Ionut - updated description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've did some research regarding this, and I couldn't find any custom option in the documentation to resolve this issue. I've came up with an easy fix where you can modifiy the `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` code a little bit. I hope this will help you.

Find this line of code:

`self.itemsArray.push(item);`

and replace it with this one:

```
self.itemsArray.splice(self.findInputWrapper().index(), 0, item);
```

You can do a `console.log($("input").tagsinput('items'));` to see the returned `array` after you change the tags.

`.push()` adds value to the end of an `array`, but when you use `.splice()` you can specify the position where to add it.

That should fix your problem.

Comment: wow that works perfectly, but I can't seem to understand what the findInputWrapper() method is doing - @Ionut

Comment: I'm glad it worked @RwitamB. Regarding the `findInputWrapper()`, I don't think I can say it better than the comment above it, and I quote: `Returns the element which is wrapped around the internal input. This is normally the $container, but typeahead.js moves the $input element.`